# NSIS - Windows 8 PDF Viewer i.e. glcnd.exe - how to launch from nsis to show Readme

Tags: windows-8, nsis

Hi I am trying to launch the dedicated Windows 8 PDF viewer to show the readme file in windows 8.

I want to use ExecShell or equivalent method. There is no documemtation on parameterizing the input to the exe for the Windows 8 viewer.

Anyone any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to force a specific app but here you go:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!define pdffile "$desktop\test.pdf" 
!define ReaderAppId "Microsoft.Reader_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.Reader" ; This is probably unique per machine/user
!define CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER 0x4
!define IID_IShellItem {43826d1e-e718-42ee-bc55-a1e261c37bfe}
!define IID_IShellItemArray {B63EA76D-1F85-456F-A19C-48159EFA858B}
!define CLSID_ApplicationActivationManager {45BA127D-10A8-46EA-8AB7-56EA9078943C}
!define IApplicationActivationManager {2e941141-7f97-4756-ba1d-9decde894a3d}

System::Call 'OLE32::CoCreateInstance(g "${CLSID_ApplicationActivationManager}",i0,i${CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER},g "${IApplicationActivationManager}",*i.r1)i.r0'
DetailPrint HR=$0,ptr=$1
${If} $1 <> 0
    System::Call 'OLE32::CoAllowSetForegroundWindow(i$1,i0)'
    System::Call 'SHELL32::SHCreateItemFromParsingName(w "${pdffile}",i0,g "${IID_IShellItem}",*i.r2)'
    ${If} $2 <> 0
        System::Call 'SHELL32::SHCreateShellItemArrayFromShellItem(i$2,g "${IID_IShellItemArray}",*i.r3)'
        System::Call `$2->2()` ; Release
    ${If} $3 <> 0
    System::Call `$1->4(w "${ReaderAppId}",i$3,i0,*i.r4)i.r0` ; ActivateForFile
    DetailPrint HR=$0,PID=$4
    System::Call `$1->2()` ; Release
    System::Call `$3->2()` ; Release
    ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
${EndIf}
```

Comment: Hey I found a workaround using the following code:

Exec '"$WINDIR\explorer.exe" "$0\$(APP_DATA_PATH)\AppData\Readme\readme_$(LOCAL_CODE).pdf"'

Turns out Adobe Acrobat 11 has a preference for "Enable Protected Mode". If this is on then you will not be able to open PDF from nullsoft using ExecShell. So I used the above line as a workaround i.e. piggy backing off the explorer.exe process.

Thanks for your help :)